# running multiple threads simultaneously

Tags: java, multithreading

Help me please. I would like to run all threads from array in one time

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String [] folders = (new counter()).readfile();
        Thread[] threads = new Thread[folders.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < folders.length; i++) {
            threads[i] = new Thread(new MyThread(folders[i]));
        }
        startThreads(threads);
    }

    private static void startThreads(Thread[] threads) {
        for (Thread t : threads)
            t.start();
    }
}
```

Other with Executors,but in this case I have  n threader, which wait each other. 
http://joxi.ru/b6AQVP3JTJBmfbW41MA

```
 String [] folders = (new counter()).readfile();
    Thread[] threads = new Thread[folders.length];
    int size= folders.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < folders.length; i++) {
        threads[i] = new Thread(new MyThread(folders[i]));
    }
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(folders.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        Runnable worker = new MyThread(folders[i]);
        executor.execute(worker);
    }
    executor.shutdown();
    while (!executor.isTerminated()) {
    }
    System.out.println("Finished all threads");
```

Comment: You're doing it.

Comment: If the threads are short lived, it will appear that they are not running because the ones you start first will end before you start the final ones.

Comment: I have this situation http://joxi.ru/epIQVIwyTJBUYiRL4C4
When 1st has finishen, then start second and the same with other.

Comment: Take a look a ExecutorService. Is more convenient way for execute multiple threads.

Comment: You're already as close to running all threads at one time as can practically be achieved. Do you instead mean that you want to create all of the threads and have them, as close as can practically be accomplished, start processing at the same time?

Comment: Yes. start pricessing at the same time.

Comment: The best you can do is have each of the new threads wait at a barrier, and have the main thread create them all, start them all, wait briefly, and then lift the barrier.  Even that won't _guarantee_ that they all start at the same time though.

Comment: Right. Create a shared (static) cyclic barrier. Each thread waits on the cyclic barrier upon creation. Create them all. Then release the barrier (in your method above). Then it's up to the JVM and OS to schedule and run the threads, but that's as close as you'll get to running the rest of the processing in them at the same time. If the threads are very quick/small, they might still appear to run sequentially.